# Invoke-RestMethod on an app requiring Azure authentication

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

How does one invoke an API behind Azure authentication using Powershell ?
More specifically, I do want this line to work : 
`Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri 'https://contoso.com/api/Hello`

My API is on-premise (but visible on the web) and have Azure AD authentication configured and mandatory.

I wish to authenticate through Powershell programatically so I can call the API without any addtionnal interaction needed.

Currently, I obtain **401** errors when doing the `Invoke-RestMethod` whatever I do.

**About the API**

I am using the sample asp.net core c# application created through Visual Studio (using the work or school authentication method).
This process created in Azure the app registration and I did manually create a client secret in Azure.

**What I attempted**

Now, using Powershell, I filled the following

```
$Params = @{
    'client_id' = '' 
    'Redirect_URI' = ''
    'TenantID' = '' 
    'response_type'='code'

}
$ClientSecret = ''
```

From there, I did get an authorization code using :

```
$Query = "?"; $Params.Keys | % {$Query+= "$($_)=$($Params.Item($_))&"} ; $Query = $Query.TrimEnd('&')


$IE= new-object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$IE.Visible = $true
$IE.navigate2("https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($params.TenantID)/oauth2/authorize$Query")
Write-Host 'Press enter when Code is displayed in URL'

pause 
$Code = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString(([uri]$ie.LocationURL).Query)['code']
$ie.quit()
```

Finally, I am getting an access token using the following :

```
$TokenResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($Params.TenantID)/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Body @{
    client_id     = $Params.client_id
    scope         = 'User.Read offline_access'
    code          = $Code
    redirect_uri  = $Params.Redirect_URI
    grant_type    = 'authorization_code'
    client_secret = $ClientSecret
}
```

However, if I now try to call my API using:

```
Invoke-RestMethod 'https://SomeDomain.com/api/values' -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($TokenResult.access_token)"}
```

**The Result**

I do get Unauthorized **401**

**My observations**

I do believe I used successfully the method below to interact with Graph API and other Azure API. However, this does not work when calling my own API which is behind Azure authentication.

How should I make a proper call that would allow me to authenticate myself against my private API using Azure authentication ?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have not configured your API in AAD. To access  the api via your AD App, you also need to create an AD App for your api in the portal, see : [Register an app with the Azure Active Directory v2.0 endpoint.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-register-an-app) and configure it to expose APIs, See : [Configure an application to expose web APIs (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis) and [Configure a client application to access web APIs (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis). Then you will be able to call the api like Graph API, Office 365 APIs, etc.

> You can develop a web API and make it available to client applications by exposing permissions/scopes and roles. A correctly configured web API is made available just like the other Microsoft web APIs, including the Graph API and the Office 365 APIs.

Comment: It looks like what I am trying to do (calling https://contoso.com/api/Hello) might be part of the 'Configure an application to expose web APIs' link. I will dig further in that direction. Thanks.

Comment: @SagePourpre Yes, if you have further question, let me know. Or if my solution solve your issue, please accept it as the answer, thanks.

Comment: Actually, what I am trying to achieve is simply this : `Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri 'https://contoso.com/api/Hello'` should return World. Instead, I get a 401. I am unclear on how to get that work and still looking. I do get an access token. and use authorization bearer header and I can get graph api to return my infos but I want to call my api rather than one's of Azure. I am still trying to figure it out but that.

Answer (score 1):

According to your script, you need to specify your Header as `Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer "+ $TokenResult.access_token}`. There is a sample I use.

```
$Params = @{
    'client_id' = '' 
    'redirect_URI' = ''
    'response_type'='code'
    'scope' = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access'
}
$ClientSecret ='.C$S|NAYQ:q)ES2w(A)*]Xp5T-?Fx+[aKE+YtmcaX!u1!{>T*wVJ70h:Q2s'
$TeantID = 'e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb'
$Query = "?"; $Params.Keys | % {$Query+= "$($_)=$($Params.Item($_))&"} ; $Query = $Query.TrimEnd('&')


$IE= new-object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$IE.Visible = $true
$IE.navigate2("https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($TeantID)/oauth2/authorize$Query")
Write-Host 'Press enter when Code is displayed in URL'
pause 
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$Code = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString(([uri]$ie.LocationURL).Query)['code']
$ie.quit()

$TokenResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($TeantID)/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Body @{
    client_id     = $Params.client_id
    scope         = 'User.Read offline_access'
    code          = $Code
    redirect_uri  = $Params.Redirect_URI
    grant_type    = 'authorization_code'
    client_secret = $ClientSecret
}

 Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me' -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer "+ $TokenResult.access_token}
```

For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Comment: The header was definitely a problem. Thanks for that. Then, with your example, I am also able to view https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me. What I am attempting to view though is :https://Contoso.com/api/Hello, which still gives the 401 error. I will look more in depth to Custom API Scopes to try to figure it out.

Comment: For a logged in user, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54997626/invoke-restmethod-on-an-app-requiring-azure-authentication for a simple solution.